# Search in SQL with LIKE

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-like

I have problem with searching in SQL with LIKE. I want SQL LIKE to search in all characters which can be mix. Let me show you.
           DB users:

```
----------------------------------------------
id   fname   lname   phoone   email
----------------------------------------------
1    John    Smit    51451    john@gmail.com
----------------------------------------------
2    Maria   Doul    878988   maria@gmail.com
----------------------------------------------
3    Bob     Coul    879333   bob@gmail.com
----------------------------------------------
```

The SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(fname, lname, phone, email) LIKE
'%Smi%514%'
```

The SQL above is working fine. But I want to search also in reverce way like that:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(fname, lname, phone, email) LIKE
'%Smi%514%John%'
```

The SQL above returns NULL because 'John' is before 'Smi' in CONCATENATION. Is there any way to make SQL query do search in both ways.

Comment: Why do you need to `CONCAT`? Why not just a simple `WHERE fname LIKE xyz AND lname LIKE abd AND phone LIKE...`?

Comment: Stop using `CONCAT`. Use `WHERE fname like '%Jo%` and lname like `%Smi%'` instead.

Comment: Because I am creating an app which can be able to search by multiple fields. I.E. in search box you can search by 'fname' and 'lname' OR 'fname' and 'phone' OR every field in table OR only one field in table.

Comment: Then write your SQL to do so properly, instead of using `CONCAT`, or arrange your search values to match the order you're `CONCAT`enating the columns.

Comment: Your `concat()` call is going to prevent the database from using indexes to execute your query, making your query very slow.

Comment: @Preacher . . . The wildcards at the beginning of the `like` pattern are going to have the same effect, so indexes will not be used for these queries.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a separate `like` for each search term, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE CONCAT(fname, lname, phone, email) LIKE '%Smi%'
    AND CONCAT(fname, lname, phone, email) LIKE '%514%'
    AND CONCAT(fname, lname, phone, email) LIKE '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider

```
FULLTEXT(fname, lname, phone, email)
```

together with

```
MATCH(fname, lname, phone, email) AGAINST('+John +Smith +514' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```